# C# calling deviceIOControl with complex structures

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, deviceiocontrol

So I am trying to write a C# wrapper to talk to one of our device drivers. (creating unit test) The driver is new, but coded against old c++ headers, so the structure layouts are defined, and can't really change.

So I have replicated the c++ structures the device is expecting DeviceIOControl to pass in.

**Update #3 -** *changing the code to demo code that has the same issue. Also cleaning up the question to be more usable to others, see my answer below*

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public class Points
{
    public int id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]  
    public int[] x = new int[10];
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    public int[] y = new int[10];
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public class Shape
{
    public int name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    public Points[] p = new Points[10];
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack1)]
public class GeoShape:Shape
{
    public int top;
    public int left;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    public int[] v = new int[10];
};
```

My call to `deviceIOControl` fails, because on the driver side it checks the size of the buffer passed in. On the C# side, I my object is too small as `Marshal.SizeOf()` returns `52` as a size, when it should be `852`, if I add the `Size=` to the `StructLayout` attribute, the function will "pass", but I am fairly sure the data is not being correctly passed.

I am fairly sure the issue is this `public Points[] p = new Points[10];` I think Marshal.StructToPtr() is not correctly marshaling this as it essentially a multi-dimensional array.

**So I guess my questions is this even possible?** Seems like C# could be smart enough to know how to create the right amount of space in memory for that array of structure.. but maybe not?

Alternatives I thought of that "could" work.

1. Write custom serailizers that convert the object to a byte[] and back, with zero meta-data. - Not ideal.
2. Would it be possible to write a mixed clr c++ dll and try to use that as an wedge. However my concerns, am I just going to have the same issue, but just in managed c++? Or even in mixed mode I would have to write a managed class to wrap the un-manged object to use it in c#. But the issue becomes how to pass that into deviceIOcontrol, if I do it from c# than will have the current issue of trying to marshal stuff correctly? Or if I pass it into a C++ call that calls DeviceIOControl, than i need to know how to get to the un-manged type of each manged object passed in.
3. Just write c++ functions that create the objects and call deviceIOControl, less idea as the parameters could get out of control?
4. Give up and do it all in C++, I am actually try to write unit test for my hardware, and newer cpp unit test in VS do integrate fairly nicely...

I also saw this earlier question, and gave it a try, however I think my scenerio is a little different. [Un-/Marshalling nested structures containing arrays of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934274/un-marshalling-nested-structures-containing-arrays-of-structures)

```
 struct Points
{
    int id;
    int x[10];
    int y[10];
};


struct Shape
{
    int name;
    Points p[10];
};

struct GeoShape :Shape
{
    int top;
    int left;
    int v[10];
};
```

**Updated 2**
I should clarify that I am trying to send an object to the driver, not receive one back (not yet atleast)

this is how I am calling it.

```
public static bool SetObject(SafeFileHandle device, DeviceControlCode ioctlCode, Object obj)
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj.GetType());
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);

            // call the dviceIOControl method
            return Control(device, ref ioctlCode, ptr, size, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
```

Comment: There's no way to tell where you went wrong, given that you didn't post the C++ declarations.  Of course you ought to consider C++/CLI, it can read the .h file directly.  With non-zero odds that you learn enough about it to be able to write correct C# declarations.

Comment: Well I am fairly sure that issue is my C# struct is not the same size, when I call in C# marshal.Sizeof() with my structure I get a size of 156 when it should be 7776. Basically c# doesn't know how to correctly Marshal the structure.

Comment: @Han Passant I toyed with that a limitless bit, but I don't think C# can see those unmanaged structs, and if it did how would I call DeviceIOControl without having to do some kind of Marshal again.

Comment: Figured it out! will post answer soon-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what's on the headers but as a starting point consider reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) about when to use **struct** or **class**

As an alert... are you sure about Pack = 1? Do you have a #pragma setting it to 1?

If you provide the related .h code it would be easier to check what might be wrong. Anyway, with the available information, I would do it like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct VENUS_FORMAT4
{
    public uint Top;    
    public uint Left;                                                           
    public uint Rows;                                                           
    public uint Columns;                                                        
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.MAX_CD_ROWS)]
    public uint[] V65Rows;                    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.MAX_CD_COLS_DD2)]
    public uint[] CDCols;                 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.MAX_DD_SECTIONS)]
    public uint[] DDSections;             
}
```

The rest is basically the same as above except in **VENUS_VM4_DEVICE_FORMAT4IL** which you will have to "replicate" the fields because you cannot inherit when using structs (in C# (type values)).

Also, if on the C++ side you have **unions** this is not going to work and you should use **LayoutKind.Explicit** and **FieldOffset**.

Comment: I could change from class to struct. I don't think that is an issue?. I should also note that I got one other IOCTL call to work, but it had a MUCH simpler structure. Am I 100% sure about the Pack, no but it's worked for me before. I think I am union free. I will have to think about posting the header contents, it's rather lengthy and messy.

Comment: @NateGates, you can post only these structures related code as a start. Does it have any #pragma pack at all? Because it might have worked before, but it depends on the packing alignment on the c++ side.

Comment: are you asking if the c++ had a pragma pack? I still think the issue is that my Marshal.SizeOf returns (156 vs. 7776) a different size of the structure than the c++ code does. And my driver uses that size to verify that the object is the structure. I fairly sure the C# just doesn't know how to marshall my structure correctly.

Comment: As far as I can tell we are not doing any pragma pack in the header file.

Comment: @NateGates, beside what I wrote I don't really see any problem. You may want to conside c++\cli like Hans Passant suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are embedding structs inside structs, you are going to need to use C# structs rather than classes so that your structures are values rather than references. This means that you will have to give up on using inheritance. You can translate your structures like so:

```
public struct Points
{
    int id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    int[] x;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    int[] y;
};

public struct Shape
{
    int name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    Points[] p;
};

public struct GeoShape
{
    int name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    Points[] p;
    int top;
    int left;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    int[] v;
};
```

With these definitions, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GeoShape))` evaluates to 892. Note that although you claim that the correct value is 852, that is not the case. The size of your C++ structure is 892.

If you want to avoid repeating the definition of `Shape` in `GeoShape` you could embed it:

```
public struct GeoShape
{
    Shape shape;
    int top;
    int left;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    int[] v;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix it buy doing the following 2 things.

1. I changed my first class to be a struct and used the `fixed` keyword.
2. I removed the `pack=1` value on the `StructLayoutAttribute`.

   `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public struct Points
   {
       public int id;
       public unsafe fixed int x[10];
       public unsafe fixed int y[10];
       //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)] 
       //public int[] x = new int[10];
       //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
       //public int[] y = new int[10];
   };`

Comment: No need for fixed here. It's easy to do without and makes your life lots easier.

Comment: Fix is the only way I could get it to work. What else would you suggest?

Comment: Well, with that attitude I give up. No fun helping somebody who starts off like that. Do it your way.

Comment: Well, it's easy to avoid fixed, but you've decided that it can't be done and chastised me for not reading the question.

Comment: Sorry, I am just frustrated as I feel people are not listening. But if you choose not to help, there is little I can do at this point, other than apologize for my rudeness.

Comment: Get rid of Pack, use struct, and UnmanagedType.ByValArray. Layout is the same as fixed.

Comment: I thought I tried that.. but I can try it again. Do I need to use struct on all my classes?

Comment: Yes. You need values rather than references.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping to avoid that, as it means in order to simulate inheritance, I either need to flatten by object, or declare variables of the other structs. I will in the morning, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a benefit to that over fixed.. I know fixed syntactically isn't as nice.

Comment: Is Marshal.SizeOf getting the size of the reference rather than the object itself?

Comment: @NateGates, Marshal.SizeOf gets the size of the object, that's why you either pass the base type or the created object itself. Regarding your solution, I'm a little confused since I wrote that in my answer and I thought you've tested it, including my doubts about the "pack".

Comment: @tweelt, credit where credit is due, you right in doubting the pack and probably the structs. Similar worked on previous IOCTL call I implemented and I found it in numerous other examples, so I trusted it. Also the documentation for the pack value seemed to make sense for me. That being said, why the down vote guys? My answer is technically correct, and just a subset of David's answer.

Comment: @NateGates, down vote was not mine but I suspect you got it because you wrote that the "fixed" helped solving your problem, which "ByValArray"  and "SizeConst" should do exactly the same without unsafe code. Maybe edit this post and write the solution in a clear way so others may profit from it. Cheers

Comment: @tweellt No I didn't think it was  you. But whoever did it, I think went out of their way to down vote a couple of my older posts (the down votes happened at the same time). I used to like stackoverflow, but I fear it's becoming hostile site. Anyways, thanks for your answer and help, I should of listened to you sooner.